# Using WM_MOUSEMOVE/WM_NCMOUSEMOVE to update specified area

Tags: windows

My perpose: When cursor hover on the specified area , a rectangle, filled with red brush. When cursor out of this area, filled with blue brush.
So I handle with WM_MOUSEMOVE/WM_NCMOUSEMOVE message(depend on the area, client zone or non-client zone), according the paramater of the cursor positon, I do defferent paintings.
Howerver,If I spliped faster, it do not work correctly.
[image: look at the min button , which my cusor was out of the area, it still been painted like activated]

```
case WM_NCMOUSEMOVE: {
    UINT HITPOS = wParam;
    POINT pt={GET_X_LPARAM(lParam),GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam)};
    BOOL active_flag=(GetActiveWindow()==hwnd);
    Frame_NCDraw(hwnd,&active_flag);
            
    if(HITPOS==HTMENU) Frame_PopMenu(hwnd,pt);
    
    TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
    tme.cbSize=sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
    tme.dwFlags=TME_NONCLIENT;
    tme.hwndTrack=hwnd;
    tme.dwHoverTime=HOVER_DEFAULT;
    TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
    return 0;
} break;
case WM_NCMOUSELEAVE: {
    BOOL active_flag=(GetActiveWindow()==hwnd);
    Frame_NCDraw(hwnd,&active_flag);
    TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
    tme.cbSize=sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
    tme.dwFlags=TME_CANCEL;
    tme.hwndTrack=hwnd;
    tme.dwHoverTime=HOVER_DEFAULT;
    TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
} break;
```

I think this may be something with the spin of each WM_MOUSEMOVE message has been triggered.
Compared with the max/min/close button on window non-client zone, no matter how fast I sliped over , it still can work well. How did it do that ?

Comment: What do you mean it's not working correctly?

Comment: when cursor on area A, area A was fill by brush with color red,
when cursor out of area A， area A was filled by brush with color blue.
Sometime it woks ok. When I sliped more faster, area A doesn't been filled correct.

Answer (score 0):

If the mouse is moving fast, your program [can receive not all mouse messages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031001-00). I think in your case, while the mouse moves to a new position, your program still handles a message with an older position, thus the wrong output.

To handle this you can check mouse position in other handlers, for example `WM_TIMER`.

At startup (typically in `WM_CREATE` handler) you should create the timer:

```
#define ID_MY_TIMER  750
void SetupTimer(HWND hwnd)
{
  //Set timer for every second
  if( !SetTimer(hwnd, ID_MY_TIMER, 1000, (TIMERPROC) NULL))
    handle error;
}
```

In your WndProc add `WM_TIMER` handler:

```
case WM_TIMER:
{
  if( wParam == ID_MY_TIMER )
  {
    TODO:
    Get mouse position (for example GetCursorPos, it returns cursor
    position in screen coordinates), compare it with the previous position.
    If the position changed, issue a redraw command (seems it is Frame_NCDraw
    call in your case).
    Save the current position as previous position

    //Set timer
    SetupTimer(hwnd);
  }  
  break;
}
```

At closing (typically `WM_DESTROY`) kill the timer:

```
KillTimer(hwnd, 1);
```

Comment: First , thank you for your answer. I'm not trying what you suggested yet. 
I just found out serval days ago before your answer , After some little changes , it seems worked.  Message handle for WM_NCMOUSEMOVE , code `tme.dwFlags=TME_NONCLIENT` changed to `tme.dwFlags=TME_NONCLIENT|TME_LEAVE`, I don't know why.